# ptvsd remotely debugging from Django's dev server port binding error

Tags: python, django, docker

Python process we are limited to binding to one IP address. Trying to run `python manage.py runserver` after adding the `ptvsd` lines results in an error. Is there a way around this?

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 14, in main
    ptvsd.enable_attach(address=('0.0.0.0', 18080), redirect_output=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ptvsd/attach_server.py", line 96, in enable_attach
    ptvsd_enable_attach(address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ptvsd/_remote.py", line 75, in enable_attach
    patch_multiprocessing=ptvsd.options.multiprocess)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 2017, in settrace
    wait_for_ready_to_run,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 2068, in _locked_settrace
    debugger.connect(host, port)  # Note: connect can raise error.
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 914, in connect
    s = start_client(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ptvsd/pydevd_hooks.py", line 132, in <lambda>
    _start_client = (lambda h, p: start_client(daemon, h, p))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ptvsd/_remote.py", line 58, in <lambda>
    start_client=(lambda daemon, h, port: start_daemon()),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ptvsd/_remote.py", line 50, in start_daemon
    _, next_session = daemon.start_server(addr=(host, port))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ptvsd/daemon.py", line 161, in start_server
    self._server = create_server(addr.host, addr.port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ptvsd/socket.py", line 79, in create_server
    server.bind((host, port))
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

**manage.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import dotenv

def main():
    dotenv.read_dotenv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '.app.env'), override=True)
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings')
    try:
        # for debug
        if os.environ['APP_MODE'] == 'DEBUG':
            import ptvsd
            ptvsd.enable_attach(address=('0.0.0.0', 18080), redirect_output=True)

        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**docker-compose.yml** (excerpt)

```yaml
command: sh -c "./wait-for-it.sh db:5432 && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$18080"
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding it manage.py you could add it in settings:

```
if DEBUG:
    import ptvsd
    import sys
    if "runserver" in sys.argv and os.environ.get("RUN_MAIN"):
        try:
            # Only run debugger for the server.
            ptvsd.enable_attach(redirect_output=True)
        except OSError:
            print("Could not enable debugging, disabling. Exception:")
            traceback.print_exc()
```

The default port is 5678.
Here is my docker-compose content:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: beHired_dev
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "5678:5678"
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file: .env
    environment: 
      SECRET_KEY: ${SECRET_KEY}
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: ${DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE}
```

In case you're using VSCode:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "beHired_dev",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5678,
            "host": "localhost",
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "/code"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```